# Problems with Mobile template of Blogger

Tags: blogger

I'm trying to fix this problem with [my blogger blog](http://felicementesposa.blogspot.it/): When I open it from any mobile device and I click then on an image, the image is displayed "blocked".

I can't scroll it to see the full image, it remains like cut. I can see just a piece of the image and I cannot zoom in or zoom out with fingers.

How can I solve this problem?
I have already checked the whole template, but without results

[image: here a screenshoot]

Answer (score 0):

Thats called a light box

To disable it
go to settings, posts and comments and put no against Showcase images with Lightbox.

Also see meta viewport tag(you can google it) related to zooming in and out on mobile devices

Comment: I want to keep the lightbox. 
And i have already looked for the viewport tag, but without result. I wouldn't write on this forumt if i didn't need help. I have already done a lot of searches online by my self :-(

Answer (score 0):

Change the mobile template from "Template > Mobile > Setting >>> Choose

"Yes. Show mobile template on mobile devices"

and then choose any of them from list..
I recommend to choose "Simple" because its not heavy as the other mobile templates and its responsive and user friendly too..

Answer (score 0):

Try using the ["viewport" meta tag](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/html/responsive-meta-tag/) in ur `<head>`

```
<meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=yes" />
```

You may google it to know more about it parameters.

U may also perhaps have the need to include `<!DOCTYPE>`in the 1st line of ur template.